# The ground is one high and one low

Tags: grammar

"There is low." my son pointed it and told me.

> "Yes, it because the ground is one high and one low."

I said.

How do I say a ground is not the same level?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, JJ!2345, but your English is so mangled that I cannot understand what you are asking; and the picture doesn't make it any clearer to me.

Comment: the second image will be more specific.

Comment: The ground is *sloped*; the ground is *not level*; the ground is *uneven*...

Comment: *Terraced* or *stairstepped* describes the arrangement of houses/rooms on your second picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That part of the house is lower," my son said.

"Yes," I responded.  "This part of the house was built on higher ground.  The other part was built on lower ground."

or

"The ground here is higher than the ground over there."

Hope that helps.  That's my best effort.

Comment: If there is a ground or road. Can I say "The ground there is lower." or "The road there is lower."

Comment: @JJ12345 yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

A building that is on a slope such as you describe is known as  [*Split Level*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&source=hp&q=split+level) .

The front and rear of the building are on different ground levels.

The term is applied irrespective of the vertical difference between the two levels.  Although common if the front and back are one complete storey different, split level can also be applied if the difference is less than one storey.  In this case the floors within the building may be on different levels in different rooms.